# How can I write a static library for sorting an unknown type array of object pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I started learning c++ not a long time ago, and I've got a tricky problem...

I have to write a static library, which is able to sort ANY type arrays of objects, and I don't really know how to do it... What to write in the header of function?

```
#ifndef SORTER

#define SORTER

class sorter
{

public:

    static array* bubblesort(array*,int size_t);
};

#endif
```

This solution is the best that I could do, but of course  it doesnt work...

What I would like to sort:

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned maxEquipment=7;
    Equipment* equipments[maxEquipment];

    equipments[0]=new Equipment(1,200);
    equipments[1]=new Printer(2,12000,12000);
    equipments[2]=new Display(3,2000,6);
    equipments[3]=new Printer(4,312000,51000); ...........
```

NOTE: I cant use any kind of sorter function from standard lirary!

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: The practical solution is to just use the standard library. Why are you ruling out the very thing that does what you want?

Comment: Ok, you cannot use standard library, but why don't you take a look at implementation of std::sort() from standard library - it will give you ideas whom to write your function since it essentially sorts objects of any type, pretty much you need to reimplement it...

Comment: I suppose a `template<>` and just saying screw the library entirely is out of the question, eh?

Comment: Isn't a qsort() function part of C? While you seem to want a bubblesort, the interface could basically remain the same. Oh, and don't put things into classes unless there's a reason for it, the above code should use a namespace, not a class with only static functions. That's just bad style.

Comment: I cant't use standard function, because i'm a univ student, and thats my homework, to rewrite it without any help...
Doomster: thats just very little part of my code... ;)

Comment: StackOverflow is for solving practical problems, and the practical solution is to use the standard library. For theoretical problems (for example, those with artificial constraints) try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which includes discussion of algorithm and data structures concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by providing a common base class that has a pure virtual function. This will allow you to enforce the requirements for sorting the array without having to worry about dealing with multiple object types.

For example if you wanted to sort on an `int` value. You would add a pure virtual to retrieve the value. The forces all derived classes to implement the member function and return a value.

```
class SortBase
{
public:
    virtual ~SortBase() {} // <-- required for polymorphism
    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};
```

One you have your base class you use it to provide a requirement for your bubble sort routine that says you must inherit from this class if you want to use me.

```
class sorter
{
public:

    static const SortBase* bubblesort(const SortBase*,int size_t);
};
```

Then you inherit from the `SortBase` class and provide an implementation for `getValue`

```
class Display : public SortBase
{
public:

    Display(int value) : value_(value) {}

    virtual int getValue()
    {
        return value_;

    }
private:

    int value_;
};
```

Your example `main` would then look something like below

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned maxEquipment=4;
    SortBase* equipments[maxEquipment];

    equipments[0]=new Equipment(1,200);
    equipments[1]=new Printer(2,12000,12000);
    equipments[2]=new Display(3,2000,6);
    equipments[3]=new Printer(4,312000,51000);

    sorter::bubblesort(equipments, maxEquipment);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the virtual method a comparison method instead?  (e.g. virtual int compare(const SortBase & compareWithMe) const = 0;  /* returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on which object is 'larger' */)?    Not every object type is representable by an integer...

Comment: Actually that may cause additional issues as the derived classes would need to be aware of other types that may not be visible. You may end up with a lot more casts than expected.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point.  I wonder if it even makes sense to try to sort an array of arbitrary mixed types.  E.g. would all Printers always come before all Displays?  If so, why?  (I hadn't read the question closely enough and I was assuming that the array would contain only one type of item, but that the type wouldn't be known at compile time)

Comment: It's not. I chose the simpler approach given that the OP is just starting out with C++ and his example is `int` based. If he needs to sort on arbitrary types it might be better as a new question since that may go the way of templates.

Comment: Okay, here's a (rather demented) way to use RTTI to make the compare() method work without every subclass having to know about every other subclass:  The sort routine first calls strcmp(typeid(object1).name(),typeid(object2).name()).  If strcmp() returns non-zero, use that as the comparison result; otherwise call the compare() virtual method to break the tie.  compare() can then safely assume that its argument is the same class as itself and only make a single downcast.

Comment: Well I'm pleasantly unbalanced so I think I'll put together an alternate solution and see how well it comes together.

Comment: I had a Twinkie and threw something together and put it up on [ideone](http://ideone.com/J9uLNA). Not sure if I want to include it in an answer though.

Comment: thanks all for helping me! I will use something similar to Captain's solution :)